# The script is missing a checkbox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was programming a script and when I want to add it to GameObject, I notice that the enable check disappeared and can't to drag to scripts to the inspector for this component `Event Script`.

I tried change the names of the scripts but there aren't changes.

The script to add:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EventScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject obj;

    public SaveObjScript saveObjScript;
    public SpawnScript spawnScript;

    public void InitObject(){
        Debug.Log("OBJETO A ACCIONAR ES: " + saveObjScript.getObject().name);
        //obj = saveObjScript.getObject();
    }

    public void ChangeColor(){
        InitObject();
        Renderer rend = obj.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.color = Random.ColorHSV();
    }

    public void RemoveObj(){
        InitObject();
        Destroy(obj);
        spawnScript.mTotalObjetos --;
    }
}
```

[image: Script disabled]

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't let me drag the other scripts I have associated with it." are you saying you can't drag **into** Event Script's `Save Obj Script` or `Spawn Script` or **out of** them? You can't drag out of them because they're null, and there's nothing to drag out of them.

Comment: @Ruzihm Maybe I expressed myself wrongly. I can't drag the scripts to the one in the inspector. Because that component is locked.

Comment: 1. It's not locked (see my answer) and 2. you can't drag script assets into MonoBehaviour fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has no checkbox because it doesn't implement any built-in methods like `Start` or `Update` or `FixedUpdate` that care about whether the component is enabled.

From the [`MonoBehaviour` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html):

> Note: There is a checkbox for disabling MonoBehaviour on the Unity Editor. It disables functions when unticked. If none of these functions are present in the script, the Editor does not display the checkbox.

Comment: I don't understand. I always use scripts without `Start`,`Update` and `FixedUpdate`, unless you need it and never get blocked. I don't understand the Note either. Could you be clearer?

Comment: @Calvin The checkbox only serves to "enable/disable" the script. An enabled monobehaviour means that it will check itself for updates every frame. Since your script doesn't implement any of the monobehaviour functions (Update, OnCollission, etc.) that the script could check, this checkbox would do nothing.